# Show $\{a_n\} \rightarrow L $ and $a_n \leq K$ for every n, then $L \leq K$

Tags: real-analysis

Show $\{a_n\} \rightarrow L $ and $a_n \leq K$ for every n, then $L \leq K$

Pf (so far)

Let $\epsilon > 0$

Define $n(\epsilon) = \epsilon/(K-L)$

Let $n> n(\epsilon)$ and $a_n \leq K$

$\Rightarrow a_n -L \leq K-L$

$|a_n - L| \leq$

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose $L > K$ then let $\epsilon= L-K $ and use definition of limit you will have contradiction